# Cannot see Jmter in Influxdb measurement

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, continuous-integration

I was trying to interact jmeter and influx db but getting as ERROR o.a.j.v.b.i.HttpMetricsSender: Error writing metrics to influxDB Url: http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=ITM&bucket=JMter, responseCode: 401, responseBody: {"error":"unable to parse authentication credentials"}

Could anyone please help me.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [InfluxDB 2.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) and it has different authorization system comparing to InfluxDB 1.x.

You need to provide [influxdbToken](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/admin/tokens/view-tokens/) parameter along with other Backend Listener settings:

[image]

Otherwise downgrade to [InfluxDB 1.x](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1/introduction/install/) and follow instructions from [JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana) article